# Usage of Floquet's Method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

I'm treating with a nonlinear bidimensional system of ODE, in which one of my fixed points is non-hyperbolic, that is,  its eigenvalues has ($\Re(\lambda_{1,2}) = 0$). Therefore, I cannot say anything about its stability from the linear analysis once it does not satisfy [Hartman-Grobman theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hartman%E2%80%93Grobman_theorem). To overcome this difficulty I want to use [Floquet's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floquet_theory) to define the stability of the closed orbit, but apparently this should be used for linear systems. My doubt is: Can I use Floquet's method in the linerized system? If not, is there any nonlinear kind of Floquet's treatment?

Comment: I do not understand: If your *equilibria* are nonhyperbolic then you do not get any information at all through the Floquet theory: it deals with *periodic orbits*. Incidentally, regarding stability of equilibria: have you heard about [Lyapunov functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lyapunov_function)?

Comment: Yes, but isn’t a matrix with purely imaginary eigenvalues a periodic matrix?

Comment: What do you mean by *periodic matrix*?

Comment: A matrix which satisfies the property $A^{n+1} = A$ with $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Those two things are totally different, having nothing more in common than the name.  A *periodic* solution means periodic in $t$ (the independent variable), whereas a periodic matrix has something to do with matrix iteration.  Incidentally, the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix}0&2\\-2&0\end{bmatrix}$$ has purely imaginary eigenvalues, $\pm 2i$, and is not periodic in your sense.

Comment: So, can’t I apply floquet method for non linear systems?

Comment: You can apply the Floquet theory to the *linearization* along a *periodic* solution of a time-periodic, or an autonomous, system of ODEs.

Comment: Suppose that I have the following ODE describing the rate of variation of the radius, $$\begin{bmatrix} dr/dt = w \\ dw/dt = \frac{1}{2} f(r) \end{bmatrix}$$  I know that, $(r = r_{*}, w = 0)$ is an equilibrium point of the ODE and the eigenvalues of jacobian in this point are purely imaginaries. Can I find floquet multipliers and expoents from this jacobian?

Comment: This is an *equilbrium* of an *autonomous* ODE system, and talking about the Floquet theory for the linearization of the system at that equilibrium makes no sense (in the time-independent case, the Floquet theory trivializes to the theory of linear homogeneous ODEs with constant coefficients).